# Transform node session to Firebase User Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I run on a Node server a Facebook Messenger Chatbot linked with Wit.ai.

When a Messenger User talks to my bot, my code verifies if this user has a session created and then respond to him. It works very well.

```
// This will contain all user sessions.
// Each session has an entry:
// sessionId -> {fbid: facebookUserId, context: sessionState}
const sessions = {};
const findOrCreateSession = (fbid) => {
  let sessionId;
  Object.keys(sessions).forEach(k => {
    if (sessions[k].fbid === fbid) {
      sessionId = k;
      var uid = fbid;
      console.log('jai dejaaaa ma session'+fbid);
    }
  });
  if (!sessionId) {
    var uid = fbid;
    sessionId = new Date().toISOString();
    sessions[sessionId] = {fbid: fbid, context: {}};
    console.log('n cree ma session'+fbid);
  }
  return sessionId;
};
```

Now I would like to replace this by a real Firebase User Authentication System, secure data, store Facebook id (bid) like that.

```
const findOrCreateSession = (fbid) => {
    let user;
    // create custom token with fbid
    admin_firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            console.log('user signed in');
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            // create custom token with fbid
            var uid = fbid;
            admin_firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid).then(function(customToken) {
                // Send token back to client
                admin_firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).then(function() {
                    console.log('user signed in');
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    // ...
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
            });
        }
    });
    return user;
};
```

Is it a good method? Am I on the good way to do this? I really don't know what I am doing.

I test step by step but there are a lot of things that I don't understand.

If you can help me, it will be very cool. Thank you.

Comment: The code creates a token and signs in to Firebase with it, so that it's essentially impersonating the Facebook user. What are your specific concerns about the code?

Comment: My problem is I really don't understand the logic with Firebase auth (it's also hard to translate From English to French ...). I just want to know if it is a good way to authenticate users from Facebook Messenger Chat and keep track of them during the Chat. Thank you M. van Puffelen for helping me.